# SQLite select next and previous row based on a where clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to be able to `get` the next and previous row using SQLite.

```
id  statusid  date
168 1   2010-01-28 16:42:27.167
164 1   2010-01-28 08:52:07.207
163 1   2010-01-28 08:51:20.813
161 1   2010-01-28 07:10:35.373
160 1   2010-01-27 16:09:32.550
 46 2   2010-01-30 17:13:45.750
145 2   2010-01-30 17:13:42.607
142 2   2010-01-30 16:11:58.020
140 2   2010-01-30 15:45:00.543
```

For example:

Given **id 46** I would like to return ids **160** (the previous one) and **145** (the next one)

Given **id 160** I would like to return ids **161** (the previous one) and **46** (the next one)
etc...

**Be aware** that the data is ordered by `statusId then dateCreated DESC` and **HAS** to work using SQLite.

```
select * from @t order by statusId, dateCreated desc
```

Test data created in sql server...

```
set nocount on; set dateformat ymd;
declare @t table(id int, statusId int, dateCreated datetime)
insert into @t
select 168,1,'2010-01-28 16:42:27.167' union
select 164,1,'2010-01-28 08:52:07.207' union
select 163,1,'2010-01-28 08:51:20.813' union
select 161,1,'2010-01-28 07:10:35.373' union
select 160,1,'2010-01-27 16:09:32.550' union
select  46,2,'2010-01-30 17:13:45.750' union
select 145,2,'2010-01-30 17:13:42.607' union
select 142,2,'2010-01-30 16:11:58.020' union
select 140,2,'2010-01-30 15:45:00.543'
```

Using SQL server 2005+ this would be fairly trivial!

**EDIT:**

Here's the same test data script but for **SQLite** which is the focus of the question.

```
create table t (id int, statusId int, dateCreated datetime);
insert into t
select 168,1,'2010-01-28 16:42:27.167' union
select 164,1,'2010-01-28 08:52:07.207' union
select 163,1,'2010-01-28 08:51:20.813' union
select 161,1,'2010-01-28 07:10:35.373' union
select 160,1,'2010-01-27 16:09:32.550' union
select  46,2,'2010-01-30 17:13:45.750' union
select 145,2,'2010-01-30 17:13:42.607' union
select 142,2,'2010-01-30 16:11:58.020' union
select 140,2,'2010-01-30 15:45:00.543';
```

**EDIT 2** Please note that the data is not a good example so I have change the `id 146` to `46`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is a lot more complicated than it first appears.  The two order by fields have to be handled separately and then combined with a union and grab the appropriate result.  To get both previous and next, we need another union, so we end up with a union with sub-unions.

This works with the supplied data.  I tested many inputs and got the right previous/next outputs.  When using, make sure you get ALL instances of `146` to replace.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  t1.*
    FROM    t t1,
            (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    t
                WHERE   id = 146
            ) t2
    WHERE   t1.statusid = t2.statusid
      AND   t1.dateCreated >= t2.dateCreated
      AND   t1.id <> 146

    UNION

    SELECT  t1.*
    FROM    t t1,
            (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    t
                WHERE   id = 146
            ) t2
    WHERE   t1.statusid < t2.statusid


    ORDER BY             
            t1.statusid DESC,
            t1.dateCreated 

    LIMIT 1
)

UNION

SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT  t1.*
    FROM    t t1,
            (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    t
                WHERE   id = 146
            ) t2
    WHERE   t1.statusid = t2.statusid
      AND   t1.dateCreated <= t2.dateCreated
      AND   t1.id <> 146

    UNION

    SELECT  t1.*
    FROM    t t1,
            (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    t
                WHERE   id = 146
            ) t2
    WHERE   t1.statusid > t2.statusid


    ORDER BY             
            t1.statusid,
            t1.dateCreated DESC

    LIMIT 1
)

ORDER BY             
        statusid,
        dateCreated DESC
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from theTable where id>@id order by id desc limit 1
union
select id from theTable where id<@id order by id desc limit 1
```

Comment: it's not ordered by id, it's ordered by statusid and date. Rippos didn't say that the id is sequential when ordering like this.

Comment: @zapping, the Id is not sequential, this is my problem. Sorry but this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using SQLIte primitives such as rowid (https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-primary-key/)
OR
creating your own set of rowid's based on the order that you output (possibly based on a sub-select count(*) query).

You can then do a select based on rowid-1 or rowid+1.

EDIT:
Some code. Mostly for my own reference.

```
-- create a new table with the desired order
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tt;
CREATE TABLE tt AS
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY statusId, dateCreated DESC;

-- remove all primary's (rowid's)
VACUUM;

-- create new table from ordered one, and add ascending rowid
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ttt;
CREATE TABLE ttt AS
SELECT rowid, * FROM tt;

-- create a new table with the row before and after the desired row
-- still need to work out how to do this with a variable for easily changing the id
SELECT t1.*,t3.*,t4.*
FROM ttt t1
LEFT JOIN ttt t3 ON t3.rowid=((SELECT CAST(rowid AS INT) FROM ttt WHERE ttt.id=46)-1)
LEFT JOIN ttt t4 ON t4.rowid=((SELECT CAST(rowid AS INT) FROM ttt WHERE ttt.id=46)+1)
WHERE t1.id=46;
```